# What happens when buildpack is updated

Tags: cloud-foundry

All apps on our team use a buildpack named **ruby_latest_buildpack**.  It's currently a renamed version of ruby_1_7_27_buildpack.  We're about to make it become ruby_1_7_28_buildpack.

What will happen to deployed and running applications when we update ruby_latest_buildpack? If we restart an application, will it continue to run under the environment that was created by the buildpack **at deploy time**, or will it start to pickup features provided by the updated buildpack?

Answer (score 1):

Once droplet is created(created while staging process) all the frameworks and runtime(which are essentially provided by Buildpacks) are already in Image. So if you just restart your application old buildpacks will be used. If you want to use updated buildpacks you will have to restage your application.

Comment: This isn't true: `Buildpacks are part of Image called Droplet`. Buildpacks are not part of the droplet, they are their own entities, however, the spirit of what you're saying is true. The binaries and items contributed by the buildpack are part of the Droplet. The droplet is created during staging. A simple restart just reuses the existing Droplet. To create a new Droplet, you need to restage.

Comment: Maybe also worth mentioning, there are no "linked" buildpacks so "ruby_latest_buildpack" is unique and so is "ruby_1_7_27". If you `cf update-buildpack` and change "ruby_1_7_27" to use "ruby_1_7_28", you're not changing "ruby_latest_buildpack". You'd need to also `cf update-buildpack` "ruby_latest_buildpack" as well.

Comment: Daniel what i meant was once Droplet is created, since their function is to provide framework and runtime environment it becomes part of Image which is immutable. But yeah i get why you said that it was wrong, i have edited my post.